# Class library with Parse throws error

Tags: c#, parse-platform, class-library, typeinitializeexception

I am attempting to develop a class library with Parse.com in it.

I have created an empty, clean class library, then using Nuget, added Newtonsoft.Json, Parse and Parse.NetFx45

I have then added a simple "Hello World" function taken from the Parse.com website and created a function in the class library.

Here is my function:

```
public async static void testParse()
{
    ParseClient.Initialize("MyApplicatonID", "My.NetKey");

    var testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
    testObject["foo"] = "bar";
    await testObject.SaveAsync();
}
```

I have then added a Unit Test project, referenced my class library and written a test as follows:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestParse()
{
    Experior.ParseFunctions.testParse();
}
```

When I run the test it throws the following error at the `ParseClient.Initialize` line of:

> System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled Message: An unhandled
>   exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll Additional information: The type initializer for
>   'Parse.ParseClient' threw an exception.

I did some searching around one of the threads I read suggested that Parse doesn't like being wrapped in a class library...

So, I thought, I will test the same code in a Windows Forms project and call the code from a simple button.

And it works perfectly!

Can anyone see anything I am doing wrong or suggest what the problem could be please?

Any hints/tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which line of your code throws an exception?

Comment: @Tarec "When I run the test it throws the following error at the ParseClient.Initialize"

Comment: Remove the async and check the behaviour (you'll need to call `Save` instead of `SaveAsync` if it exist, or manually wait for completion). nUnit for example has the ability to create async tests in order to execute async methods properly, furthermore you need to await `testParse` in any case. Alternatively change your test signature to `public async void TestParse()` and do not forget the await.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Samuel I have amended my code as follows:

```
using Parse;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ExperiorWrapper
{
public class ParseFunctions
{
    public static async Task testParse()
    {
        ParseClient.Initialize("xxxx", "xxxx");

        var testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
        testObject["foo"] = "bar";
        await testObject.SaveAsync();
    }
}
}
```

and the test now looks like this:

```
[TestMethod]
    public async Task TestParse()
    {
        await ParseFunctions.testParse();
    }
```

The other important thing I tripped up on is that the Newtonsoft.Json, Parse and Parse.NetFx45 HAD to be added as references to the Test project to make it work...

HTH